# Can I register 2 instances of the same DbContext class for 2 different databases?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In `ConfigureServices` I call

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
                   services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
                    options => options.UseSqlServer(
                        _configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionString)));
}
```

but now I want a second instance of `MyDbContext` that uses different connection string. How to correctly do it so dependency still works? Is the only way is to create an empty `MyDbContext` subclass and register it this way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Core multiple connection strings on same DBContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616408/entity-framework-core-multiple-connection-strings-on-same-dbcontext)

Comment: @SteveNorwood He does, what I proposed creating dummy empty subclass. Is there another way?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Dependency Injection will need some way of working out the difference between your two database connections, and this is the simplest way that I can see. I know with HttpClients you can give them names (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#named-clients) but this is quite different and I can't see anything like this for EF