# Is it possible to add multiple DbContext Factories for the same DbContext to the services collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Is it possible to add more than 1 DbContextFactory, for the same DbContext, to the services collection in an ASP.NET Core application?

For example, I am trying the following code ...

```
services
  .AddDbContextFactory<WibWorkspaceContext, WibWorkspaceContextFactory>();

services
  .AddDbContextFactory<WibWorkspaceContext, WibWorkspaceSystemContextFactory>();
```

I want two different factories for the same DbContext. One factory always signs in using a SQL "admin" account and the other uses user-specific accounts.

I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work, though. How can I specify which one to use on the side of things that grab the service? For example, here's a constructor receiving the service - how does it know which one to use?

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IDbContextFactory<WibWorkspaceContext> contextFactory, IConfiguration configuration)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: perhaps this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616408/entity-framework-core-multiple-connection-strings-on-same-dbcontext

Comment: another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816215/dynamically-change-connection-string-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Just register the child classes instead of the parent

Comment: The DI system distinguishes by type so it has no way to know which implementation to inject (well it'll inject the last one by default)